# How to install and Certificates HTTPRIO connection

Tags: web-services, delphi, http

I import the WSDL file. GetCA from the WSDL file that were imported rust is in the function.

The following example of a block of code when I run the program.

Where the function is called whoami in receipt of the certificate has not been installed error. How to install and Certificates HTTPRIO connection?

```
begin
  HTTPRIO1.WSDLLocation := defWSDL;
  HTTPRIO1.Service := defSvc ;
  HTTPRIO1.Port := defPrt ;
  HTTPRIO1.URL := defURL;

  b := WhoAmIMessage.Create;
  a := ReplyMessage.Create;
  Cert := TElX509Certificate.Create(nil);

  try
    F := TFileStream.Create(CertFile, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    CERT.LoadFromStreamPFX(f, CertPass);
    F.Position := 0;

    HTTPRIO1.HTTPWebNode.OnBeforePost := OnBeforePost;

    Trs := GetCA(True, ' ', HTTPRIO1);

    B := Trs.WhoAmI;
    ShowMessage(BoolToStr(B.IsAuthenticated));
  finally
    a.Free;
    b.Free;
    Cert.Free;
    FreeAndNil(F);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You seem to be using Eldos's software. Have you asked in [their forums](https://www.eldos.com/forum/list.php?FID=7)? They usually answer within the hour.

Comment: BTW, this question is basically incomprehensible as-is.

Comment: Thank you for message  i asked in [Eldos Forums](https://www.eldos.com/forum/read.php?FID=7&TID=4939)